A question on properties of Mass forms.
I am studying Proposition 3.3.3 from "Automorphic Forms and L-functions for the group $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$" by D. Goldfeld, and I need a clarification regarding the behavior of Maass forms as $\text{Im}(z) \to \infty $.
The definition of a Maass form of type $n \in \mathbb{C}$ in this context is as follows:

It is a function $f:SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \mathbb{H}\xrightarrow{}\mathbb{C} $ i.e invariant under the action of $ SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $ on $ \mathbb{H} $,
$ f $ is a square-integrable (with repspect to $dz=\frac{dx.dy}{y^2}$), non-zero eigenfunction of the hyperbolic Laplacian $\Delta $ on the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H} $ and $\Delta f=n(n-1)f,$
$ \int_0^1 f(z) \, dx = 0. $

In Proposition 3.3.3, the statement is made that if $ f$ is a Maass form of type 0 or 1, then it must be constant. The justification provided contains the claim that, because $ f $ is a Maass form, it is bounded as $ \text{Im}(z) \to \infty $.
Here is my question:
Why does the fact that $ f $ is a Maass form imply that it is bounded as $ \text{Im}(z) \to \infty $?
I understand that Maass forms are square-integrable, which imposes some constraints on their growth, but I thought that the condition of square-integrability only suggests that $ f$ cannot grow faster than $ y^2 $ as $ y \to \infty $. Why does this lead to $ f $ being bounded, rather than merely preventing rapid growth?
Thank you very much for any help!

If you read the rest of the chapter, you'll see that Maass forms have Fourier expansions involving Whittaker functions. The fact that they are square-integrable means that these Whittaker functions decay exponentially as $\Im(z) \to \infty$ (the only other possibility is that they grow exponentially, contradicting square-integrability). This in turn forces $f$ to be bounded as $\Im(z) \to \infty$.

That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much !
